# Deploy app code from Gitlab to azure app service using sync method

Tags: gitlab, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-configuration

I've deployed an application with the code on a GitLab repository in the Azure App service.
I used the deployment center to configure the integration with GitLab (external).
I used the advanced tools to create the key to be set in Gitlab.
I managed to deploy successfully, but now I am getting this error message when I try to sync:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied\nfatal: Authentication failed for 'http://*****/platform/api.git/'\n\n/usr/bin/git fetch origin --progress
```

I tried creating a new Azure app service and I followed the same documentation provided by Microsoft, I've got the same error message:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied\nfatal: Authentication failed for 'http://******/platform/api.git/'\n\n/usr/bin/git fetch origin --progress
```